# SplideJS Slider - Not Moving

Tags: slider, webflow, splidejs

I have a webflow project where I am trying to configure SplideJS as the main product image slider on an ecom product template page.

I am struggling to get the slider working. All the styling is there but when I press the left and right arrows the slider doesnt move.

Here is a read-only link to my webflow page: https://preview.webflow.com/preview/vortex-air-a65509cdd1731d065deab0112e40?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=vortex-air-a65509cdd1731d065deab0112e40&preview=35992ea90db64efb45fa94ba9a05d4e2&pageId=645d014aa0344e5972f59e2e&itemId=645d54fa0254bbffca3e135e&workflow=preview

here is a link to the live site: https://vortex-air-a65509cdd1731d065deab0112e40.webflow.io/product/vortex-air-tm-pro-bladeless-tower-fan-heater-cooler

Any help would be amazing! Thanks

-- UPDATE -- it seems to be fine on product pages where the product does not have a varient. Which feels quite strange. I have commented out all other code I have added to the site, to check for any potential conflicts, but still the same activity.

This is my head code:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/css/splide.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

This is my body code:

```
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/js/splide.min.js
"></script>

<script>
 new Splide('.splide', {
      type: 'slide', // Specify the type as "slide"
      perPage: 1,
      perMove: 1,
      gap: 0,
      arrows: true, // Enable arrows
      pagination: false, // Disable pagination
      speed: 600,
    }).mount();
</script>
```